# Android Visualizer class, example of "snoop" mode?

Tags: android

I want to make a small app utilising the visualizer class, but cannot find any examples of the visualizer being used in "snoop" mode i.e. the session ID is 0.

All examples I have found use a MediaPlayer or are from Live Wallpapers.

I tried to take this code: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer, and change it to use the audio playing on the device, but I am totally lost on how to unlink the MediaPlayer and tell the Visualizer to use the currently playing audio.

Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated :)

Comment: Well, did you try to just pass `0` instead of `player.getAudioSessionId()` to the `Visualizer` constructor? If your intention is to save the global audio output or stream it to another device, I'm afraid you'll be disappointed. The `Visualizer` class is only meant for visualizing purposes, and therefore the quality of the audio you can get from it is quite low.

Comment: After some hacking about, I got the code working with the currently playing audio. I am trying to make heads n tails of the code at the moment. I am unable to find where I increase the sampling time (how fast to update the renderers). Also, what is the difference between Audio Data and FFT Data? (the line renderer uses audio, the bars uses fft)

Comment: The audio is data is for visualizing the waveform, while the FFT data is for drawing spectrograms (i.e. showing the energy in different frequency bands).

Comment: Think I understand :) So how do I go about increasing the "refresh rate" for the Visualizer?

Comment: The rate is specified in the call to [setDataCaptureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html). I don't know what the limits are, though.

Comment: I can't mess with any code right now but ill look tomorrow. Looking at the renderer classes in the linked source code, do you know how I can stop the paint objects "echoing" and fading out? Id just like a fast drawn single line. Also is there a way to switch the visualizer to using the mic input? Id like to offer both device audio and mic input as the interaction method.